# Extract properties from an iModel

Tags: imodeljs, bentley-itwin

Is there a way like an api endpoint to extract properties from an iModel in JSON or other format? This question is regarding the api endpoints available through the iTwin services from Bentley. I have tried looking in the data management and other services as well but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way to get properties in iTwin.js is to use [Presentation](https://www.itwinjs.org/learning/presentation/) APIs.

There's a sample that shows how to do that: https://www.itwinjs.org/sample-showcase/?group=Viewer+Features&sample=property-formatting-sample. It shows several approaches for how to get properties - approach #1 and #2 are simpler as they load properties directly into components that are part of iTwin.js (PropertyGrid & Table), approach #3 is a bit more complex and shows how get raw property data and extract some values from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iModelReport application and this is what it uses

```
  private writeRow(fileName: string, columns: any[], statement: ECSqlStatement) {
    let valuesRow:any = [];
    const replacer:any = (_key: string, value: any) => (value === null) ? undefined : value;

    for(let i=0; i< columns.length; i++) {
      const value:any = statement.getValue(i).value;
      valuesRow.push(JSON.stringify(value, replacer));
    }
    const outRow = valuesRow.join(";");
    this.writeLine(fileName, outRow);
  }
```

The result is json, and here I convert it to csv

ecSQL can be reviewed here
https://www.itwinjs.org/learning/ecsqltutorial/